# dataGridView not updating c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have filled the datagridView using the code below

```
    this.empinfoTableAdapter1.Fill(this.empData.empinfo);
```

but when i am updating the table from gridview its updating the orginal database. But not showing the update in the form.

I have searched google and found similar question. But most of them are custom data binding. Not using

```
  this.empinfoTableAdapter1.Fill(this.empData.empinfo);
```

so, i posted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ASP.Net application then you need to call `DataBind()` like:

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

If its WinForm application then you need to assign the `DataSoure` again like:

```
GridView1.DataSource = this.empData.empinfo;
```

Comment: Your answer solved my half problem. but after updating the data if i call dataGridView1.DataSource = this.dbDataSet.empinfo; then the dataGridView showing me the updated data. But if i close the form and reopen it then the form is filling with old data. What i guess is empinfoTableAdapter is keeping the data the time when i run the project. Isn't there any way to refresh the enpinfoTableAdapter.

Comment: Not really sure about your problem, but TableAdapter is suppose to fill the DataTable, you need to call the Fill method again before rebinding, if you need latest records.